# How to get latest active record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my data. Member can be enroll multiple times and can change plan anytime,I need to get C_level data for latest near to getdate that is **"8/1/2017"** for ID 1, For ID 2 doesn't have latest data, that case we have to show 12/31/2016 record.

```
ID Start_Date End_Date   C_Level
1  1/1/2016  12/31/2016    1
1  1/1/2017  8/1/2017      2
1  9/1/2017  12/31/2017    3
1  1/1/2018  12/31/2018    0
2  1/1/2015  12/31/2015    2
2  1/1/2016  12/31/2016    3
```

Comment: What do you exaclty mean by "latest data" ? Why ID1 has "latest data" while ID 2 doesn't have it ?

Comment: ID   enrolled till 2019, but ID2 is no longer active in system, he might be expired/ switched to different insurance company.

Comment: ID 1 is enrolled c_level "2" until 8/1/2017 and from 9/1/2017 he is switched over to c_level "3" , if I execute query I should get "8/1/2017" rows and if I execute query on 9/1/2017 I should get 9/1/2017

Comment: Try to reword or give more examples. Not clear in current form.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what example is required here, it all about health care insurance enrollment, For example, I have enrolled year start and after 3 months I have changed plan or enrolled different plan next year, data will change time to time.

Comment: Why do you need the `8/1/2017` row for ID1? It has two other rows with later end dates. Why isn't the row with `12/31/2018` the latest?

Comment: Good question William, The one 12/31/2018 is future date, Member has so much money he is enrolled till 2018 :), but current running is 8/1/2017

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements right, then this query should give what you want:

```
WITH current_running AS (
  SELECT to_date( '8/1/2017','mm/dd/rrrr') As Current_running_date
  FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          row_number() Over (partition by id order by end_date desc ) As rn,
          c.Current_running_date
   FROM Table1 t
   JOIN current_running c
   ON c.Current_running_date >= ANY( t.Start_Date, t.End_Date )
)
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33de0/10

---

For current_running_date = `2017-08-01` it gives:

```
| ID |            START_DATE |              END_DATE | C_LEVEL | RN | CURRENT_RUNNING_DATE |
|----|-----------------------|-----------------------|---------|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2017-08-01 00:00:00.0 |       2 |  1 | 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00.0 |       3 |  1 | 2017-08-01T00:00:00Z |
```

while for current_running_date = `2016-07-15`

```
| ID |            START_DATE |              END_DATE | C_LEVEL | RN | CURRENT_RUNNING_DATE |

|----|-----------------------|-----------------------|---------|----|----------------------|
|  1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00.0 |       1 |  1 | 2016-07-15T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0 | 2016-12-31 00:00:00.0 |       3 |  1 | 2016-07-15T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Wow, looks good to me, I'm validating all scenarios, Please allow sometime to give feedback on this, You are awesome :)